# Add Control to website via Code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing some controls for an asp.net website and i want make this controls contain .ascx file and .dll file.
I dont want upload site for every control.
so is there a way that make this control add to site via code like adding module in **DotNetNuke**.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand the question, are you making a dll or an ascx? Anyways, so long as it has a class definition, you can instantiate it ...

Comment: I made an ascx file and put its codebehind in dll.  it basically similar to DNN Module

Answer (score 0):

You may need to consider using WebParts:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/UsingWebPartsInASPNet20.aspx

Or this link:

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/webparts/intro.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom controls. You can do that by deriving your control class from "System.WebUI.Webcontols.Control". You need to override CreateChildControls method for the UI.